What is the source of deadlock in Producer Consumer problem with circular buffer
I have a very stereotypical producer-consumer problem with a bounded buffer. It is running fine locally but when I submit to online I am getting an error that my Submission did not run 5 times successfully, indicating a deadlock. I am curious what could be the source for this? I feel like I did wait() and notify() correctly and I don't know what other than that could be causing a deadlock.
I believe it has to be an error in Buffer.java, but I am including all the files in case.
Buffer.java:
package HW4;

public class Buffer {
    
    private double[] array;
    private int empty;
    private int full;
    private int capacity;

    //Initialize values
    public Buffer(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.array = new double[capacity];
        this.empty = capacity;
        this.full = 0;
    }

    //Produce method
    //Check if full; add value to array; notify()
    synchronized public void produce(double value) throws InterruptedException {
        while (full == capacity) {
            wait();
        }

        array[full] = value;
        full++;
        empty--;
        notify();
    }

    //Consume method
    //Check if empty; remove value from array; notify()
    synchronized public double consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while (empty == capacity) {
            wait();
        }

        double retValue = array[capacity - empty - 1];
        array[capacity - empty - 1] = 0d;
        full--;
        empty++;
        notify();
        
        return retValue;
    }
}

Main.java:
package HW4;

public class Main {
    
    public static final int iterations = 1000000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a buffer item along with a producer and consumer instantiation
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer(1000);
        Producer producer = new Producer(buffer, iterations);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(buffer, iterations);

        //Create a thread for both the producer and consumer; 1 of each
        Thread prodThread = new Thread(producer);
        Thread consThread = new Thread(consumer);

        //Start each thread
        prodThread.start();
        consThread.start();

        //Attempt to join the threads after they are done running.
        try {
            prodThread.join();
            consThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR IN MAIN.\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting!\n");
    }
}

Producer.java:
package HW4;

import java.util.Random;

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    
    private Buffer buffer;
    private Random random;
    private int iterations;

    //Import buffer item and create Random item for generating doubles
    public Producer(Buffer buffer, int iterations) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.random = new Random();
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }
    
    //Loop to create 1,000,000 items and add them to the buffer
    //Maintain total value for outputting
    @Override
    public void run() {
        double total = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            double bufferElement = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
            
            try {
                buffer.produce(bufferElement);
                total += bufferElement;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR in PRODUCER.\n");
            }

            if (i % 100000 == 0 && i != 0) {
                System.out.println("Producer: Generated " + i/1000 + ",000 items, Cumulative value of generated items=" + formatDouble(total));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Producer: Finished generating 1,000,000 items");
    }

    private String formatDouble(double value) {
        return String.format("%.3f", value);
    }
}

Consumer.java:
package HW4;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private Buffer buffer;
    private int iterations;

    //Import buffer item
    public Consumer(Buffer buffer, int iterations) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }

    //Loop to remove 1,000,000 items from the buffer
    //Maintain total value for outputting
    @Override
    public void run() {
        double total = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            try {
                double bufferElement = buffer.consume();
                total += bufferElement;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR in CONSUMER.\n");
            }

            if (i % 100000 == 0 && i != 0) {
                System.out.println("Consumer: Consumed " + i/1000 + ",000 items, Cumulative value of consumed items=" + formatDouble(total));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer: Finished consuming 1,000,000 items");
    }

    private String formatDouble(double value) {
        return String.format("%.3f", value);
    }
}


Are you sure you getting deadlock? I expect this code to fail because ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

I was wrong. I didn't understood that you Buffer is actualy LIFO. I expected from buffer to be FIFO

You don't need empty variable because capacity - empty == full, and while (empty == capacity) is just while (full == 0)

It is a weird approach, but this should be a functional FIFO circular buffer. Full is how many buffer slots are populated and empty is how many buffer slots are empty. So when there is exactly 1 item in the buffer empty = 999. array[1000 - 999 - 1] = array[0]. So it is extracting from the correct location

Yes it works. And I was unable to reproduce your deadlock problem. If you still able to reproduce it take stacj dump it will tell you which tread blocked on which condition,
